# Python "Bad file descriptor" when reading from pipe

Tags: python, python-3.x, pipe

I'm trying to start a subprocess and pass a pipe file descriptor to it to read from. However when I try to read from the pipe in the child process I get "Bad file descriptor", even though I can read from the pipe in the parent process just fine.

Here's the parent process:

```
import subprocess
import sys
import os

r, w = os.pipe()

os.set_inheritable(r, True)

p = subprocess.Popen(["python3", "client.py", str(r)])

os.write(w, b"hello")

p.wait()
```

And here's the child process:

```
import sys
import os

r = int(sys.argv[1])
print("[Client]", os.read(r,  5))
```

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: It seems like `os.set_inheritable()` isn't working. I tried a similar script where I ran `lsof -p $$` in the child, and it didn't show the pipe FD as open.

Comment: Hmm, is this a bug or am I doing something wrong? calling get_inheritable in the parent process returns true. but for some reason the child process can't use the file descriptor.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From the official Python [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#inheritance-of-file-descriptors):

> Using the subprocess module, all file descriptors except standard streams are closed, and inheritable handles are only inherited if the *close_fds* parameter is `False`.